# Deep linking not working in chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, deep-linking

I am trying to do deep linking such that when someone opens a link from mobile browser, it either opens the app, if it is installed or opens the play store link to download the app.

Here is my URI :

```
intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=com.example.android;package=com.example.android;end
```

When I type this in Mozilla Firefox app on Android, it opens my app if it is installed or opens the play store link if it not installed. But, when I type the same thing in Chrome, instead of opening app or play store, it just does a google search. What is wrong with my solution and how do I make it work?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you _typing_ the URL, or _pasting_ it into the address box?

Comment: if you paste the url in browser will not direct to app, above intent works only if you directs url (user click link and that link open ) to browser then only browser open app which you are trying to open

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a known `wontfix` bug in Chrome 40+ (see the Chromium project ticket [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=484815) for the full story).

Essentially, the Chrome team feels that if a user actually *types* something into the address bar, no redirect should ever happen. As you've discovered, this is counter to behavior in all other browsers.

Fortunately it's unlikely a user would actually type an `intent://` URI by hand. If you wrap the URL inside a link on a webpage, or offer a link to another page and then issue a redirect of some kind (so that you can detect the user agent and not show a 'broken' `intent://` link to users on other browsers), it should work correctly.

If you don't want to handle all these edge cases, you could also try a free service like [Branch.io](http://branch.io) *(full disclosure: I'm on the team).*

Comment: will Branch.io work for redirects to deep links too? I have a problem with a deep link to the Android Pay app. If I type the link in the address bar I'm moved to the app correctly but if I use a redirect, then google chrome on my android device send me the the Play Store website. This is happening only on Google Chrome Browser for Android.

Comment: @DMEM I think it would be better if you can open a new question with a few more details. Throw the `deep-linking` tag on there and I'll see it

Comment: Thanks @Alex Bauer . I contacted Google Support and their engineering team is looking into this issue so for now I will wait. I will leave an update here when I hear back from them.

Comment: @DMEM ever heard something about this ?

Comment: @LukeFilewalker Google fixed my issue by simply replacing the deeplink URL I was using. The correct URL for the Google Pay app should be: https://www.android.com/payapp/savetoandroidpay/<JWT_OF_WALLET_CARD_HERE>

Comment: well my co-worker says if google team believer in ghost