# Handling external links in android webview

Tags: android, webview, external-links

I want to open my app and load the URL when specific links are clicked.

This is my Manifest for handling external links.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.android.com" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.android.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

And for handling incoming links this is the code

```
    intentData = getIntent().getData();
    if(intentData !=null){
        loadUrl = intentData.toString();
    }else {
        loadUrl = "https://www.android.com";
    }
    webView.loadUrl(loadUrl);
```

Now when I clicked https://www.android.com from external app like whatsapp its loaded in webview but the webview is attached to whatsapp. Check screenshots below.

[image: Normal Webview]   [image]

---

And if anyone can give me any hints or guide me on how to open my app when I open the URL(https://www.android.com) from Google Chrome(in my phone) will be a great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this line in Manifest file of your Activity which is Handling that intent to avoid such problem.

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Answer (score 1):

For second part of your question:

> And if anyone can give me any hints or guide me on how to open my app
>   when I open the URL(https://www.android.com) from Google Chrome(in my
>   phone) will be a great help

take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37089686/6950238) answer:

"Essentially, the Chrome team feels that if a user actually types something into the address bar, no redirect should ever happen. As you've discovered, this is counter to behavior in all other browsers."

Comment: Thanks , for the info. [Branch.io](https://branch.io/) is a useful thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can find detail implementation here, https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

You have to override methods, and handle clicks.