# Deep linking Android from chrome

Tags: android, deep-linking

The app opens when I load from applications. However, it does not load when I try to load from he chrome. This his is my manifest file

```
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
         <data android:scheme="http"
         android:host="spectacles"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37089686/6950238) answer:

"Essentially, the Chrome team feels that if a user actually types something into the address bar, no redirect should ever happen. As you've discovered, this is counter to behavior in all other browsers."