# Firebase Dynamic Link when typed into Android Address Bar

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

As you can see here, i want to change the behavior of my Firebase Dynamic Link when it is typed into the Android Browser, because right now it redirects me to the PlayStore instead of Deep Linking into the app. How can i achieve such behavior?

[image: Current Dynamic Link Preview]

Answer (score 0):

While creating dynamic link you need to specify either you want to open any specific URL in browser or you need to open your app.

If you need to open your app when dynamic link gets clicked then at the time of creating new dynamic link you need to choose your app from drop down list instead of giving url.

If the app is installed already it will open it otherwise redirect you towards playstore.
For opening app from deep link you need to write code into your activity that can handle the coming deep link.

Chrome doesn't open the deep links some time due to wontfix bug in Chrome 40+.
Mentioned in [link for detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37089686/6236752)

Same is the case with Firebox and other browsers.
[firefox broswer issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/169)

[Related Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085960/why-is-typing-a-firebase-dynamic-link-in-a-browser-leads-to-a-different-result-t)

Comment: yes i did all of these things, and the app opens perfectly when i click the link from anywhere, but if i manually enter it in the browsers search bar, it doesnt work

Comment: So there is no possible way to deeplink into my app from the browser? thats quite unfortunate

Comment: unfortunatly yes but you can  test it from notepad or from any messaging client.

Comment: Did you find any solution for both platforms android and iOS?