# Why is url with custom uri scheme not launching my app from chrome but works fine if launched from firefox

Tags: android, uri, deep-linking

I'm trying to launch a uri with custom scheme from chrome and expected behavior is a popup saying "open with x app".

As per https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html I've added an intent filter with scheme="abcd"

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="abcd" />

            </intent-filter>
```

So it i type **abcd://** from firefox, it shows an option to launch it in my android application, but same from chrome doesn't work, it googles it instead.

explored other questions, tried setting activity:exported = "true" for my activity as well, it's not working.

found this somewhat relevant : https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme/issues/156 but It'd be really helpful if someone could explain it in simpler terms.

Comment: Check [https://stackoverflow.com/a/37089686/3022836](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37089686/3022836)