# Pasting Firebase Dynamic Link into Chrome address bar opens playstore instead of app

Tags: android, google-chrome-app, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

At first, here is a working example of my dynamic link in debug view:

[image]

The dynamic links uses a custom scheme like `https://myapp.something/Xyz1`

Now I come to the different behaviors using Google Chrome App on Android.
I would expect all of them either open the PlayStore (as in the image) or
open the App. But they behave diffently.

Info: I have the app installed.

1. Opening Google Home-Screen widget and **pasting** link: Opens App
2. Opening Google Home-Screen widget and **typing** link: Opens App
3. Opening Chrome App, open new tab and **pasting** into **google search bar**: Opens App
4. Opening Chrome App, open new tab and **typing** into **google search bar**: Opens App

Those 4 are basically the same opening mechanics. But now comes why I am puzzled:

5. Opening Chrome App and **typing** into **address bar**: Opens App

**But**

6. Opening Google Chrome App and **pasting** into **address bar**: Opens Playstore

Why does **pasting** the link into the address bar of a new tab open the playstore instead of the app? (Which would be favored by me).

Edit: Just in case, I know there is a `wontfix` for chrome. ([Other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37089686/6236752)). But what is the difference between pasting and typing here?

Comment: Really interesting read. Never tried all these cases exhaustively for my dynamic links. Who would have known, pasting on a new tab vs on the opening tab is somehow different. Im reconfirming, the results in your analysis matches with my FDLs too. Looked around a bit myself, cannot tell why they are different yet. Perplexed. Let us know, if you find anything.